# How to download and run grayLog2 code base

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I am new to GrayLog I need to run GrayLog code in eclipse so that I can do some code changes and explore it

so far I have cloned the code from git  [here](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server.git)

I'm not sure how to (which type of project ) import it to eclipse and run it

please help

Answer (score 0):

Graylog is a Maven project.

You can import it like any other Maven project into Eclipse: [Using Maven within the Eclipse IDE - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html)

Comment: If I import using Maven how do I run it as a single project  I can c multiple projects inside it like web-interface etc etc I'm completely new to this please help